# How to transfer a Terraria PC map to Xbox One?

Tags: pc, xbox-one, terraria-console

I've looked around, and do not see a place in my Xbox One to look at specific files, so I have no clue how to drop maps onto my external drive to play Terraria on.

*Background info: I bought an Xbox One for myself for Christmas, and it came with a 350gb hard drive and some of the smallest games take like 10gbs to download so I bought a 4tb drive for 100 dollars, much less than they wanted for a much smaller internal Xbox One drive by the way.*

So how do I get a Terraria map from my PC onto my external drive, to play it on my Xbox? I've seen some kids on YouTube bragging about an all items map, but they don't show how to drop the map (transfer it from PC to Xbox).

**So what do I do?**

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. There are too many differences between the two games for them to be compatible with one another.

To make it even more impossible, when you plug an external hard drive into an Xbox One, it has to be formatted. That means all files on the drive will be wiped. So even if you put a PC map on it, it would get deleted in the format process. The same goes for when you plug the hard drive back into a PC.  You will have to format it again.

Comment: Also, I believe that YouTube video you watched was for Xbox 360.  I found a forum saying they were only able to get the all items map to work with that method. Still, with the hard drive formatting blocking you, it won't be possible.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't try to copy files manually. Depending on what you do, you might even violate the Microsoft Terms of Service.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get a PC map to Xbox 360 the rest is easy get horizon, first extract a world's file from 360 Terraria with a world on it and then download your world and replace the contents of world0.wld with the one you want save and rehash and then plug it into the Xbox 360 if the world works then upload to Xbox One and download it once it's on Xbox One.