# How do I transfer my Xbox One Terraria worlds to PC using a USB stick?

Tags: pc, terraria, xbox-one

I am trying to download a map for terraria from my Xbox One to my PC and
I'm having trouble figuring it out. How do I transfer my stuff from Xbox to PC?

Comment: i wanted to say  that i need to transfer my profil to my usb stick then to my pc

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you need to copy files from one system to another, the problem has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand. Do you want to go from Xbox to PC or PC to Xbox?

Comment: As has been said already, the two versions work completely differently, and so it’s currently impossible to do what you’re after.

Answer (score 2):

Save files between platforms are not compatible. Generally, console and PC versions of Terraria are very different, and the console versions are often behind as well.

There used to be ways to do it between Xbox 360 and PC, which involved copying files and converting them with a tool someone made. This doesn't exist or work for Xbox One, though. Depending on what is required, you would probably be violating the Microsoft TOS concerning your Xbox One.

Also, while strictly not a duplicate (because it's the other way around), a similar question and answer are found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/323710).