# i want to try to transfer my character on xbox terraria to pc

Tags: terraria-console

so I have looked into this and haven't really found a clear answer and I think I have an answer but I just want to make sure of it.

so what I want to do is transfer my character with all/most of his stuff from Xbox 360 to pc

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. An answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/355420/248985) explains why, which I'll rephrase:

Save files between platforms are not compatible because they are constructed and function differently because they're entirely separate versions of the game.

Transferring saves used to be possible with the help of a tool, but this is no longer the case, at least for Terraria.